# Как сделать, чтобы функция срабатывала сразу после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция:

```
$(cardImage).on('click', _playSequence.bind(this, true, i));
```

мне нужно, чтобы она отрабатывала сразу после загрузки страницы, а не по нажатию.

Comment: $(cardImage).click();

Comment: @Igor, не работает(

Comment: работает :). Или, по-Вашему, я подсунул Вам неработающий код?!

Comment: @Igor не работает. вот вам пример того что у меня должно получиться, только мне надо чтобы оно работало сразу после загрузки, а не при нажатии на блок.

https://codepen.io/Elesmer/pen/JONNqY

Answer (score 5):

события:
**DOMContentLoaded** – означает, что все DOM-элементы разметки уже созданы, можно их искать, вешать обработчики, создавать интерфейс, но при этом, возможно, ещё не догрузились какие-то картинки или стили.
**load** – страница и все ресурсы загружены, используется редко, обычно нет нужды ждать этого момента.

```
function ready() {
  alert('DOM готов');
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Событие **DOMContentLoaded** происходит на document и поддерживается во всех браузерах, кроме IE8-.
Обработчик на него вешается только через **addEventListener**

все дело в том что

Answer (score 0):

Замените `click` на `load` или

```
$(function(){
    $(cardImage).click(); 
})
```

Comment: замнел сначала $(cardImage).on('load', _playSequence.bind(this, true, i));
не работает, второй вариант так же не действует, может я не туда вставляю ( вставил сразу под тем.

Comment: @Андрей Павлишин, как результат?

Comment: не работает, всеровно

Comment: https://codepen.io/Elesmer/pen/JONNqY, вот, пример того что должно получиться, только отрабатывать оно должно сразу после перехода на страницу, а не после клика по блоку.

Answer (score 0):

Просто напиши вот так за место того клика или рядом:

Вызов функции воспроизведения напрямую с нужными параметрами. Первый параметр клик, второй id

```
_playSequence(true,0);
```

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Demo.
 */
var demo = (function(window, undefined) {

  /**
   * Enum of CSS selectors.
   */
  var SELECTORS = {
    pattern: '.pattern',
    card: '.card',
    cardImage: '.card__image',
    cardClose: '.card__btn-close',
  };

  /**
   * Enum of CSS classes.
   */
  var CLASSES = {
    patternHidden: 'pattern--hidden',
    polygon: 'polygon',
    polygonHidden: 'polygon--hidden'
  };

  /**
   * Map of svg paths and points.
   */
  var polygonMap = {
    paths: null,
    points: null
  };

  /**
   * Container of Card instances.
   */
  var layout = {};

  /**
   * Initialise demo.
   */
  function init() {

    // For options see: https://github.com/qrohlf/Trianglify
    var pattern = Trianglify({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      cell_size: 120,
      variance: 1,
      stroke_width: 0.5,
      color_function : function(x, y) {
        return '#e37b7c';
      }
    }).svg(); // Render as SVG.

    _mapPolygons(pattern);

    _bindCards();
  };

  /**
   * Store path elements, map coordinates and sizes.
   * @param {Element} pattern The SVG Element generated with Trianglify.
   * @private
   */
  function _mapPolygons(pattern) {

    // Append SVG to pattern container.
    $(SELECTORS.pattern).append(pattern);

    // Convert nodelist to array,
    // Used `.childNodes` because IE doesn't support `.children` on SVG.
    polygonMap.paths = [].slice.call(pattern.childNodes);

    polygonMap.points = [];

    polygonMap.paths.forEach(function(polygon) {

      // Hide polygons by adding CSS classes to each svg path (used attrs because of IE).
      $(polygon).attr('class', CLASSES.polygon + ' ' + CLASSES.polygonHidden);

      var rect = polygon.getBoundingClientRect();

      var point = {
        x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,
        y: rect.top + rect.height / 2
      };

      polygonMap.points.push(point);
    });

    // All polygons are hidden now, display the pattern container.
    $(SELECTORS.pattern).removeClass(CLASSES.patternHidden);
  };

  /**
   * Bind Card elements.
   * @private
   */
  function _bindCards() {

    var elements = $(SELECTORS.card);

    $.each(elements, function(card, i) {

      var instance = new Card(i, card);

      layout[i] = {
        card: instance
      };

      var cardImage = $(card).find(SELECTORS.cardImage);
      var cardClose = $(card).find(SELECTORS.cardClose);

      _playSequence(true,0); //Воспроизвидение анимации без клика

      $(cardImage).on('click', _playSequence.bind(this, true, i));
      $(cardClose).on('click', _playSequence.bind(this, false, i));
    });
  };

  /**
   * Create a sequence for the open or close animation and play.
   * @param {boolean} isOpenClick Flag to detect when it's a click to open.
   * @param {number} id The id of the clicked card.
   * @param {Event} e The event object.
   * @private
   *
   */
  function _playSequence(isOpenClick, id, e) {

    var card = layout[id].card;

    // Prevent when card already open and user click on image.
    if (card.isOpen && isOpenClick) return;

    // Create timeline for the whole sequence.
    var sequence = new TimelineLite({paused: true});

    var tweenOtherCards = _showHideOtherCards(id);

    if (!card.isOpen) {
      // Open sequence.

      sequence.add(tweenOtherCards);
      sequence.add(card.openCard(_onCardMove), 0);

    } else {
      // Close sequence.

      var closeCard = card.closeCard();
      var position = closeCard.duration() * 0.8; // 80% of close card tween.

      sequence.add(closeCard);
      sequence.add(tweenOtherCards, position);
    }

    sequence.play();
  };

  /**
   * Show/Hide all other cards.
   * @param {number} id The id of the clcked card to be avoided.
   * @private
   */
  function _showHideOtherCards(id) {

    var TL = new TimelineLite;

    var selectedCard = layout[id].card;

    for (var i in layout) {

      var card = layout[i].card;

      // When called with `openCard`.
      if (card.id !== id && !selectedCard.isOpen) {
        TL.add(card.hideCard(), 0);
      }

      // When called with `closeCard`.
      if (card.id !== id && selectedCard.isOpen) {
        TL.add(card.showCard(), 0);
      }
    }

    return TL;
  };

  /**
   * Callback to be executed on Tween update, whatever a polygon
   * falls into a circular area defined by the card width the path's
   * CSS class will change accordingly.
   * @param {Object} track The card sizes and position during the floating.
   * @private
   */
  function _onCardMove(track) {

    var radius = track.width / 2;

    var center = {
      x: track.x,
      y: track.y
    };

    polygonMap.points.forEach(function(point, i) {

      if (_detectPointInCircle(point, radius, center)) {
        $(polygonMap.paths[i]).attr('class', CLASSES.polygon);
      } else {
        $(polygonMap.paths[i]).attr('class', CLASSES.polygon + ' ' + CLASSES.polygonHidden);
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Detect if a point is inside a circle area.
   * @private
   */
  function _detectPointInCircle(point, radius, center) {

    var xp = point.x;
    var yp = point.y;

    var xc = center.x;
    var yc = center.y;

    var d = radius * radius;

    var isInside = Math.pow(xp - xc, 2) + Math.pow(yp - yc, 2) <= d;

    return isInside;
  };

  // Expose methods.
  return {
    init: init
  };

})(window);

// Kickstart Demo.
window.onload = demo.init;
```

```css
/* CARD */

.card {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 29%;
 height: 0;
 margin: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.card__container {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 /* prevents flicker */

 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.card__container--closed {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.card__image {
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 500px;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.card__container--closed .card__image {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.card__content {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 30px 40px 22px;
 color: #888;
 background: #fff;
}

.card__container--closed .card__content {
 margin-top: 0;
 padding: 5px 16px;
 pointer-events: none;
 background: transparent;
}

.card__caption {
 font-size: 2em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 35px 30px 0px;
}

.card__container--closed .card__caption {
 font-size: 1em;
 max-width: none;
 padding: 30px 10px;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
 transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.card__title {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1;
 margin: 5px 0 0 0;
 color: #3b393d;
}

.card__container--closed .card__title {
 color: #fff;
}

.card__subtitle {
 font-size: .95em;
 line-height: 1;
 margin: 5px 0 0;
 color: #777778;
}

.card__container--closed .card__subtitle {
 color: #f5f5f5;
}

.card__copy {
 font-size: 1.25em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 25px 30px 100px;
 color: #3b393d;
}

.card__copy p:first-of-type {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.card__btn-close {
 font-size: 18px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 36px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.card__container--closed .card__btn-close {
 display: none;
}

.meta {
 font-size: .85em;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 padding: 0 0 35px 0;

 -webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.card__container--closed .meta {
 visibility: hidden;
}

.meta__avatar {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.meta__author {
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.meta__date {
 margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
 .card {
  width: 46%;
  padding-bottom: 32.2%;
 }
 .card__image {
  max-height: 360px;
 }
 .card__content {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
 .card {
  width: 96%;
  padding-bottom: 67.2%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 .card__caption {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 35px 0px 0px;
 }
 .meta {
  padding: 0 0 25px 0;
 }
 .card__copy {
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 25px 0px 100px;
 }
}
/* PATTERN */

.pattern {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.pattern--hidden {
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
}

.pattern--hidden .polygon {
 transition-duration: 0ms;
}

.pattern svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.polygon {
 transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in-out, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
 transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
 transform-origin: center bottom;
 fill: transparent;
}

.polygon--hidden {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 transform: scale(0);
}
/* disable scale on firefox */

.ff .polygon {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1)!important;
 transform: scale(1)!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-b2a7b3fe212eaa732349046d8416e00a9dec26eb7fd347590fbced3ab38af52e.js"></script><script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/CardExpansion/js/vendors/trianglify.min.js"></script><script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/CardExpansion/js/vendors/TweenMax.min.js"></script><script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/CardExpansion/js/vendors/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script><script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/CardExpansion/js/vendors/cash.min.js"></script><script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/CardExpansion/js/Card-polygon.js"></script>
<body class="demo-2">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
   <!-- trianglify pattern container -->
   <div class="pattern pattern--hidden"></div>
   <!-- cards -->
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card__container card__container--closed">
      <svg class="card__image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
       <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipPath1">
         <polygon class="clip" points="0,500 0,0 1920,0 1920,500"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
       </defs>
       <image clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" width="1920" height="500" xlink:href="https://tympanus.net/Development/CardExpansion/img/a.jpg"></image>
      </svg>
      <div class="card__content">
       <i class="card__btn-close fa fa-times"></i>
       <div class="card__caption">
        <h2 class="card__title">Tristan and Isolde</h2>
        <p class="card__subtitle">A modern day love story</p>
       </div>
       <div class="card__copy">
        <div class="meta">
         <img class="meta__avatar" src="img/authors/1.png" alt="author01" />
         <span class="meta__author">Gerry Sutherland</span>
         <span class="meta__date">06/19/2015</span>
        </div>
        <p>Business model canvas bootstrapping deployment startup. In A/B testing pivot niche market alpha conversion startup down monetization partnership business-to-consumer success for investor mass market business-to-business.</p>
        <p>Release creative social proof influencer iPad crowdsource gamification learning curve network effects monetization. Gamification business plan mass market www.discoverartisans.com direct mailing ecosystem seed round sales long tail vesting period.</p>
        <p>Product management ramen bootstrapping seed round venture holy grail technology backing partner network entrepreneur beta marketing value proposition. Android stealth conversion scrum project network effects. Creative alpha long tail conversion stealth growth hacking iteration investor A/B testing prototype customer. Startup www.discoverartisans.com direct mailing launch party partnership market ramen metrics focus value proposition.</p>
        <p>Stock infrastructure seed round sales paradigm shift technology user experience focus gamification. Partnership metrics business plan stealth business-to-business. Deployment graphical user interface monetization. Twitter incubator scrum project entrepreneur branding burn rate ramen backing paradigm shift virality crowdsource.</p>
        <p>Social proof MVP ecosystem. Ramen launch party pitch deployment stealth. Vesting period MVP equity. Focus creative partnership founders iteration agile development infographic.</p>
        <p>Low hanging fruit burn rate innovator user experience niche market A/B testing creative launch party product management release. Www.discoverartisans.com influencer business model canvas user experience gamification paradigm shift startup research &amp; development iPad agile development. Strategy incubator infographic success marketing buzz A/B testing responsive web design. Traction research &amp; development pitch seed money venture niche market accelerator network effects.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```js
function init() {
  console.log('страница загрузилась');
}
window.onload = init;
```